# How to web-scrape the creator-bio on Kickstarter projects with Python & BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a finance master student and currently writing my thesis. I am analyzing factors that have an influence on the probability on successful funding on Kickstarter. I have obtained a dataset from webrobots.io, however I am missing some variables (did not get links for their full, public databases). In fact, I need information on the founder (# of projects founded before, # of projects backed, # of fb friends). This information only pops up in a window when clicking on the founders' names.

Thus, I have the URL to each of my 5000 projects in the sample and want to scrape the creator-bio for each of these links. I have started to watch tutorials (f.e."https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xQTJi2tqgk") and also tried to come up with something. When I click on the founders' name or avatar, the required pop-up window opens and when I click on 'inspect element' I found the "div" that I need. However this particular "div" is not present before I click on the link (makes sense to me). I have found a link ('a' which has the same url but then just a ".../creator-bio" in the end. I assume that there is a way to open this link and then take the information out of the required "div".

I will post the code that I have so far, but please keep in mind that I have not much experience and I tried to figure it out by myself.

Python:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/551342300/radically-efficient-
design-for-people-transport"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

links = soup.find_all("a")

for links in links:
    print "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text)

creator_bio = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "creator-bio"})

print creator_bio

for item in creator_bio:
    print item.text
```

Answer (score 1):

I navigated to the url: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/551342300/radically-efficient-design-for-people-transport/creator_bio

And it pulled up the name, city/state, last login, and other info. I believe you should scrape this page instead.

Comment: Hello Abraham, thanks for your answer!! That definitely helps and makes sense, i could just add "/creator_bio" behind all the urls and then scrape from there right? Didn't think about this haha, thanks a lot.